# develpo mobile apps using ionic and intel xdk

Tags: ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I want to create mobile apps using **ionic** and **intel xdk**.

I have already installed Intel XDK but there is no options for Ionic.

I tried to install Ionic by going to the projects page and then clicking on the "**Add bower Packages**", but it show that

```
packages not available right now, try again later..
```

please anyone help me about how can I develop mobile apps using Ionic framework and Intel XDK

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic and intel xdk is a good way to start, debug and test hybrid application.Ionic is basically combination of html 5 and cordova with little extra on the top.

What you need to do is **select HTML5 + CORDOVA project**.

Comment: thank you for your reply.....I selected **HTMl5 + CORDOVA project** as you told that **IONIC** is a combination of these two, after that a new project has been created and that is based on cordova. So I pick a IONIC from a tutorial and paste it in the index file, and this runs successfully. Thank you

Comment: It is my pleasure :D

Answer (score 1):

Use this starter template for Creating Ionic project with Intel SDK..

> https://github.com/Reinsys/intel-xdk-ionic-angularjs-starter-template

Open the unzipped folder

Open intel-xdk-ionic-angularjs-starter-template-masterfolder

Copy IonicProjectStarter folder to your projects directory and rename to "YourProjectName"

Open "YourProjectName" and rename "IonicProjectStarter.xdk" to "YourProjectName.xdk"

Open your IntelXDK software

Under Projects tab of IntelXDK, click OPEN AN INTEL XDK PROJECT

Browse to "YourProjectName" folder in your projects directory

Click and open "YourProjectName.xdk"